# What is the "some" meaning in Collect result in Scala

Tags: rdd, collect

"some" is not a special term which makes the googling seem to just ignore that search.

What I am asking is in my learning below:

```
b.collect:
Array[(Int, String)] = Array((3,dog), (6,salmon), (3,rat), (8,elephant))

d.collect:
Array[(Int, String)] = Array((3,dog), (3,cat), (6,salmon), (6,rabbit), (4,wolf), (7,penguin))
```

if I do some join and then collect the result, like b.join(d).collect, I will get the following:

```
Array[(Int, (String, String))] = Array((6,(salmon,salmon)), (6,(salmon,rabbit)), (3,(dog,dog)), (3,(dog,cat)), (3,(rat,dog)), (3,(rat,cat)))
```

which seems understandable, however, if I do: b.leftOuterJoin(d).collect, I will get:

```
Array[(Int, (String, Option[String]))] = Array((6,(salmon,Some(salmon))), (6,(salmon,Some(rabbit))), (3,(dog,Some(dog))), (3,(dog,Some(cat))), (3,(rat,Some(dog))), (3,(rat,Some(cat))), (8,(elephant,None)))
```

My question is why do I get results seems to be expressed differently, I mean why the second result contains "Some"? what's the difference between with "Some" and without "Some"? Can "Some" be removed? Does "Some" have any impact to any later operations as the content of RDD?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the normal `join` as `b.join(d).collect`, you get `Array[(Int, (String, String))]`

This is because of only the same key with `RDD b` and `RDD d` so it is always guaranteed to have a value so it returns `Array[(Int, (String, String))]`.

But when you use  `b.leftOuterJoin(d).collect` the return type is `Array[(Int, (String, Option[String]))]` this is because to handle the `null`. In `leftOuterJoin`, there is no guarantee that all the keys of `RDD b` are available in `RDD d`, So it is returned as Option[String] which contains two values

1. `Some(String)` =>If the key is matched in both RDD
2. `None` If the key is present in `b` and not present in `d`

You can replace `Some` by getting the value from it and providing the value in case of `None` as below.

```
val z = b.leftOuterJoin(d).map(x => (x._1, (x._2._1, x._2._2.getOrElse("")))).collect
```

Now you should get `Array[(Int, (String, String))]` and output as

```
Array((6,(salmon,salmon)), (6,(salmon,rabbit)), (3,(dog,dog)), (3,(dog,cat)), (3,(rat,dog)), (3,(rat,Some(cat)), (8,(elephant,)))
```

Where you can replace `""` with any other string as you require.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination but your code:  (x._2._1, x._2._2.getOrElse("")): wouldn't it return only at most two elements at most? if yes, what is the way to show all?

Comment: Yeah, it returns at most only two elements and isn't that the requirement. without using `getOrElse` it also only returns at most 2 elements.

Comment: anyway, thank you for your enlightening but sorry I can't accept this as the right answer.